# Changing file permissions doesn't seem to work

Tags: permissions

I am using this command to change the file permissions for all files and folders after navigating manually to `var/www/html/wp-content`

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

However in my ftp client I can see that folders have permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x
drwxrwsr-x
```

These should had been all consistent after the above command was executed. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
```

Comment: ok, but do you know what 'drwxrwsr-x' (with an s) mean ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work

Comment: so if I use your command, I get rid of the sticky bit forever ? I think the sticky bit comes back on its own in some plugin folders of my wordpress installation

Comment: On directories, the suid/sgid bits do something slightly different than the linked unix.se answer. Short version; it makes files created in the directory keep the same user or group ownership as the directory. This is likely desired behavior since by default in this style application, they will get their group from the httpd or your CGI process; possibly www-data, httpd, or apache.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your command but nothing happens - the permissions still have the (s) sticky bit..

Comment: what about `sudo chmod -R g-s  /dir`?